# ElasticSearch async delete? 200 just after deleting index in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

We're using ElasticSearch with the Tire gem on a Rails app. For our integration tests, we delete and recreate the index before each example, something along the lines of

```
Foo.index.delete
Foo.create_elasticsearch_index
```

Where `Foo` includes `Tire::Model::Persistence`. But we started having missing index errors from time to time when running our test suite on CI. I went ahead and enabled debugging and then I found the following in the logs:

```
# 2013-10-04 09:25:05:839 [DELETE] ("test_index")
#
curl -X DELETE http://some-server:9200/test_index

# 2013-10-04 09:25:05:840 [200]
#
# {
#   "ok": true,
#   "acknowledged": true
# }

# 2013-10-04 09:25:05:852 [HEAD] ("test_index")
#
curl -I "http://some-server:9200/test_index"

# 2013-10-04 09:25:05:852 [200]
```

As you can see, I get a 200 ok response for the DELETE request, but then when Tire does a HEAD request to see if the index exists before creating it, it still returns a 200 instead of a 404. This happens randomly, most of the times it works ok, but at some point in the test suite it will fail.

I tried waiting for a yellow status between the delete and the create operations, but it didn't work. So my question here would be, is the delete index operation asynchronous in some way? (Couldn't find anything on the ES doc about that). Is there any way to wait for the index to be deleted? (Since the yellow status doesn't work).

Edit: Thanks @PinnyM for the clarification. So all the operations through the HTTP API [are indeed asynchronous](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html). So the question that remains is, how can I wait for the index to be deleted so I can create it again?

Comment: All HTTP operations to ES are asynchronous, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before each example, you delete and recreate the index. As part of that process you could then ensure that the delete process has completed (asynchronously) by polling for the `exists` function to return `false`... In crappy pseudo-code...

```
max_wait = 5
while wait < max_wait and Tire.index("test_index").exists:
    wait some more
    if wait > max_wait:
        throw WaitedTooLongException()
```

The Tire docs for `exist` are here - essentially they are doing the same index polling you found in the debug code:
http://rubydoc.info/github/karmi/tire/master/Tire/Index#exists?-instance_method and here's the call: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-exists.html

Personally, I would adjust your tests that use the ES instance... If you put the not-exists loop at the start of the test and the index tear-down at the end of the test, then you could get two benefits. You could:

- Assert that the index didn't exist when testing started - nice and clean.
- Ask for index tear down at the end of a test and run your next test which might not need ES - possible slight speed-up depending on your App and CI implementation of test ordering.

Comment: Nice idea! I followed your suggestion, added a small `ensure_deleted` method to `Tire::Index` that would try 5 times and throw an exception if the index was still present. That was enough, since in all the cases I saw, the index was already deleted by the second request.

Also, I changed it the way you suggested (check for index absence before creation on the `before(:each)` and deleting it on `after(:each)`). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @julio.olvr - glad my psuedo-code was helpful (I'm not a Ruby dev).

Answer (score 0):

To wait for asynchronous operations to finish I am using in my RSpecs

```
collection.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!
```

Very useful when I just indexed a new document and I want to run a search on it immediately after in my spec.

the `.refresh_index!` is a blocking method. Actually I believe all `!` methods might be... have you tried the other `!` methods ?

```
collection.__elasticsearch__.delete_index!
collection.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
```

(Using ES 5.x with the appropriate elasticsearch-ruby/rails gems without Tire)